# Question on applying Expectation in Stochastic Recurrence

Tags: probability-theory, limits, stochastic-processes

I'm extremely new to discrete stochastic processes, and I have a question about the validity of applying the expected-value operator in the following problem about a discrete stochastic recurrence relation involving random variables.

Here are my assumptions: $X_t$ (random variable), $X_t$ $\in$ {0, 1, 2, ..., n} for all $t≥0$. $t$ is a discrete time index, $t$ $\in$ {0, 1, 2, ...}, and $n$ is a positive integer. I'm also defining the initial value $X_0 = n$. Also, $f$ is a positive constant, $0 < f < n$.

The recurrence relation is:

$X_t = X_{t-1} + f - 2N_{t-1}$,

where $N_{t}$ (a random variable), $N_{t}$ $\in$ {0, 1, 2, ..., $X_{t}$}, for all $t≥0$.

Also, $N_{t}$ is defined s.t. $N_{t}|X_{t}\sim\mathrm{Hypergeometric}(n, X_{t}, f)$ for all $t ≥ 0$.

I have *no* reason to believe $X_t$ is identically distributed for all $t≥0$, and in fact, {$X_t$, $t≥0$} is not even a sequence of independent r.v's. I also don't want any full answers to understanding this relation (for now) -- I'd rather figure stuff out on my own first, though I welcome hints and references to read.

**My question is:** before applying the expectation (or variance) operator on both sides, would I first need to prove *in advance* that the limit distribution of $X_t$ exists, or that a limiting distribution even exists? (Because that's something I frankly don't know how to do.)

So applying $\mathbb{E}[]$ on both sides of course would get:

$\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ = $\mathbb{E}[X_{t-1}] + f - 2\mathbb{E}[N_{t-1}]$,

and then defining $\mathbb{E}[X_t] := \alpha_t$ to get the relation,

$\alpha_t = \alpha_{t-1} + f - 2\mathbb{E}[N_{t-1}]$

treating it as a regular deterministic recurrence relation.

---

I have the same question for applying the $\operatorname{Var}()$ (variance) operator on both sides, and make the same definition as with expectation (say, define $\operatorname{Var}(X_t) := v_t$).